# Using algorithm as input for bearing in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a rather simple model:

[image]

I have one vector line  and one distance as input and I want to "draw" a line on the from the centroid of the line with the "distance" on each side. But I don't understand why I can't use the field calculator as input for the bearing any suggestion what I'm missing (The `Using Algorithm Output` is empty for the Bearing)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made a different model solving the issue with `Geometry by expression`, I transformed the geometry twice which may have been unnecessary but this is how the final model looked like:
[image: Final model]

The expression that solved the issue was:
  `make_line( project( centroid( $geometry ),  @width/2 , azimuth(start_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:32632', 'EPSG:4326')), end_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:32632', 'EPSG:4326'))) -radians(90)), project( centroid( $geometry ),  @width/2, azimuth(start_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:32632', 'EPSG:4326')), end_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:32632', 'EPSG:4326'))) +radians(90)) )`

It would probably been easier if I just translated the centroid and projected point than it only would have required one algorithm, anyhow this was at least a working solution.